# How can I check users being edited role?

Tags: cakephp

I have Owner, admin and user roles.
There's only one owner and that's me.
How can I deny admins from editing or deleting me?
Owner has id 1 so if I'm going to check in isAuthorized() if the admin is not the owner I do this: `$user['id'] != 1`.
Now how I'm going to check if the user being edited or deleted is the owner. I know how to get the user id with this: `$this->request->params['pass'][0]` but not the user role.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd have "owner" as a Role.  It's much easier to allow someone to be a normal Role-type, then keep an `owner_id` field in the items table.

That way, you can leave Roles deal with the higher-level authorization, and in the individual items action/method, you can check for ownership (often done with a custom `isOwner()` function to keep your code DRY).

In your `PostsController->edit($id)` function as an example, you can do a `find()` on the Post, then compare it's `owner_id` against `$this->Auth->user('id')` to make sure they can only edit if they're the owner.

If you want to retrieve Role and keep it available, you can do so in the AppController's beforeFilter with a normal find on the `roles` table based on the `role_id` field of the Auth->user.